# Can't change Strings into int in `[]`

Tags: ruby, typeerror

In ruby, I try to convert a String to Int in operator '`[]`' But failed.
Here is the code (my input is `14  45`):

```
STDIN.gets.split(/\s+/).each do |str|
    book = tags[str.to_i]     # book is just a new variable.  tags is an array 
end
```

the ruby will stop with an error:
`in '[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)`

So I change my code to follows(this one works well.):

```
STDIN.gets.split(/\s+/).each do |str|
  number = str.to_i     # for converting
  book = tags[number]
end
```

This one works well. But I must add one more line for converting. Is there a good way for avoiding that line?
my version of ruby is: `$: ruby --version  ==>  ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision39474) [i686-linux]`

Hi Guys, Please let me KNOW why you still want to close this topic. THANKS.

Comment: What is `tags`, `db` and `book`? And if your upper code does not work, the second part is not working either. You are probably calling `array[nil]` at `db[book]`.

Comment: @oldergod, Hi, I jsut modify it. And I don't think i'm calling array[nil]. With the same input, the second version of my code works well.

Comment: People wants to close this topic because there is a lack of information which makes it really hard for the viewers to understand your problem and/or replicate it.

Comment: Maybe you were accidentally writing one of `tags[str]` or `tags['str.to_i']`, please check.

Comment: Both of code are running good. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message you are getting will definitely **only ever** occur when you pass a `String` as an index to `Array#[]`. So you are probably not showing us the source that you are actually running. Consider:

```
a = [1,2,3]
str = 'string'

str.to_i
#=> 0
a[str.to_i]
#=> 1

number = str.to_i
#=> 0
a[number]
#=> 1

a['string']
# TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

By the way, the error message in your question is specific to Ruby 2.0.0:

```
RUBY_VERSION
#=> "2.0.0"

a = [1,2,3]
a['string']
# TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

Whereas in Ruby 1.9.3-p392 you will get this error message:

```
RUBY_VERSION
#=> "1.9.3"

a = [1,2,3]
a['string']
# TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
```