# A single row in my .csv fails to import due to TypeError: can't convert String into Integer, though others pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-1.9.3, amazon-product-api

Similar to [this question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293444/cant-change-strings-into-int-in)

When importing a CSV, I get the following Ruby 1.9.3 error: "TypeError: can't convert String into Integer"

It reads in full:

```
pry(main)> Lightbulb.import
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bundler/gems/rails-1c2717d3f5a3/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:36:in `[]'
```

I believe this is because we're passing a string (Amazon ASIN) as an index to the array in lightbulb.rb, as well as importing other data from the Amazon Product Inventory.

It works for all but on of my 35 rows. I think it is because the data for this particular Amazon product cannot be converted to an integer? I don't really know...

This is the import process which fails with one row in the CSV (listed below) where the string cannot be converted to an integer:

```
  # asin  organization_name lumens_per_watt light_output  watts life_hours  light_color
  def self.import
    destroy_all
    table = CSV.read("#{Rails.root}/vendor/data/bulb.csv", :headers => true)
    table.each do |row|
      ap = Product.find_or_save(row['asin'])
      create(
        :price => ap.lowest_new_price,
        :small_image => ap.small_image,
        :medium_image => ap.medium_image,
        :large_image => ap.large_image,
        :detail_page_url => ap.detail_page_url,
        :asin => ap.asin,
        :brand => row['organization_name'],
        :feature => ap.feature,
        :organization_name => row['organization_name'],
        :label => ap.label,
        :manufacturer => row['organization_name'],
        :product_model => ap.product_model,
        :sku => ap.sku,
        :title => ap.title,
        :total_new => ap.total_new,
        :editorial_reviews => ap.editorial_reviews,
        :efficiency => row['lumens_per_watt'],
        :brightness => row['light_output'],
        :actual_watts => row['watts'],
        :expected_life => row['life_hours'],
        :light_color => row['light_color'],
        :perceived_watts => calculate_perceived_watts(row['light_output'])
      )
    end
  end
```

Here is the full code for Product.find_or_save:

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :asin, type: String
  field :parent_asin, type: String
  field :detail_page_url, type: String
  field :item_links, type: Array, default: []
  field :sales_rank, type: String
  field :small_image, type: String
  field :medium_image, type: String
  field :large_image, type: String
  field :image_sets, type: String, default: []
  field :brand, type: String
  field :ean, type: String
  field :ean_list, type: Hash, default: {}
  field :feature, type: Array, default: []
  field :item_dimensions, type: Hash, default: {}
  field :label, type: String
  field :manufacturer, type: String
  field :product_model, type: String
  field :mpn, type: String
  field :package_dimensions, type: Hash, default: {}
  field :part_number, type: String
  field :product_group, type: String
  field :product_type_name, type: String
  field :publisher, type: String
  field :sku, type: String
  field :studio, type: String
  field :title, type: String
  field :lowest_new_price, type: String
  field :lowest_used_price, type: String
  field :total_new, type: String
  field :total_used, type: String
  field :offers, type: Hash, default: {}
  field :customer_reviews, type: String
  field :editorial_reviews, type: String
  field :similar_products, type: Array, default: []
  field :nodes, type: Array, default: []

  def self.find_or_save(asin)
    if item = where(asin: asin).first
      item
    else
      amazon_product_hash = AmazonApi.product(asin)
      attrs = ProductWrapper.parse(amazon_product_hash)
      create(attrs)
    end
  end
```

If I have one row that fails - just one! :)

```
B00B4CPKT4,Philips,56,730,13,25000,2700
```

If I remove that row, just 1 of 35, it runs perfectly. It always fails at that one row in the .csv. I have placed it first, in the middle, and last - even rewritten it to find any hidden gremlin characters.

Here is the header and first row, for example, which work flawlessly:

```
asin,organization_name,lumens_per_watt,light_output,watts,life_hours,light_color
B00BXG7UZ8,Cree,75,450,6,25000,2700
```

I tried adding `.to_i` to make `:asin => ap.asin.to_i,` but no luck!

This is the last line I see in development.log, and I see 13 instances of this line corresponding to the 13 frustrating times I tried to run Lightbulb.import with this faulty product in the bulb.csv file:

```
  MOPED: 54.234.253.6:33037 QUERY        database=heroku_app14604604 collection=products selector={"$query"=>{"asin"=>"B00B4CPKT4"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (5231.9772ms)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace that you're getting as well as the code for `Product.find_or_save` and `create`?

Comment: Could you give an example of a row that does work, the corresponding headers and your schema for that table? if "B00B4CPKT4" is the ASIN it is a string and not an integer so trying to coerce it won't work. I am curious if the other ASIN's are actually integers and these that seem to be random failures are just ASIN's that contain non-numeric characters. Sorry, I am not too familiar with Amazon's Product inventory, but if this is the case it could be that your database field (if it is an integer) can not save the string due to a type mismatch.

Comment: After a quick glance at the Amazon Product Inventory, it appears the ASIN can be a pure integer I.E. `0439064872` or a string `B00728DYG0` so this may be the case.